# Modular representations of GL(n,q)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

I wonder what is a good source to read about Modular representations of GL(n,q).
The specific question I am interested in is $GL(n,q)$ acts on $X=F_q^n$ in a natural way. If say q is prime and $q>n$ then all subrepresentations of $F_q^X$ are polynomials of degree at most $d$. 
We can consider the action of $GL(n,q)$ on $X\times X$ by $g\cdot(x,y)=(gx,gy)$. 
Does it known or how one can calculate all subrepresentations of $F_q^{X\times X}$?

Comment: $F_q^X$ is just  permutation representation